# errot :org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on, cas

I have this error when I try  to login on CAS+Active Directory

```
:org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]
```

i use CAS  3.5.2
maven 3.0.5 
tomcat 7 
windows 2008 server R2